# i have errir like Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\exapmle\index.php on line 27

Tags: php, mysql

When I run the code

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\exapmle\index.php on line 27

code is:

```
<?php
  function tweet(){
  $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tweet", 'root', '');
  $get_name = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users,tweets WHERE tby = uid");

  $get_name->execute();

  $tweets= $get_name->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
  foreach ($tweets as $tweet) {
    echo '<div class="all-tweet">
      <div class="t-show-wrap"> 
       <div class="t-show-inner">
        <!-- this div is for retweet icon 
        <div class="t-show-banner">
          <div class="t-show-banner-inner">
            <span><i class="fa fa-retweet" aria-hidden="true"></i></span><span>Screen-Name 
                Retweeted</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        -->
        <div class="t-show-popup">
          <div class="t-show-head">
            <div class="t-show-img">
              <img src="PROFILE-IMAGE"/>
            </div>
            <div class="t-s-head-content">
              <div class="t-h-c-name">
                <span><a href="PROFILE-LINK">'.$tweet->uname.'</a></span>
                <span>@USERNAMAE</span>
                <span>POSTED-ON</span>
              </div>
              <div class="t-h-c-dis">
                STATUS
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--tweet show head end-->
          <div class="t-show-body">
            <div class="t-s-b-inner">
             <div class="t-s-b-inner-in">
               <img src="TWEET-IMAGE" class="imagePopup"/>
             </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--tweet show body end-->
        </div>
        <div class="t-show-footer">
          <div class="t-s-f-right">
            <ul> 
              <li><button><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-share" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></button></li>  
              <li><button><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-retweet" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></button></li>
              <li><button><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></button></li>
                <li>
                <a href="#" class="more"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                <ul> 
                  <li><label class="deleteTweet">Delete Tweet</label></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>';
}
}


 tweet();

?>
```

In this code I will try to fetch data from users and tweet table but I can't retrieve.

Comment: Which line is #27?

Comment: <span><a href="PROFILE-LINK">'.$tweet->uname.'</a></span>

Comment: this line is 27

Comment: Did you mean the line `foreach ($tweets as $tweet) {` to loop over a list of tweets, at the moment it is looping over the fields in the 1 tweet.

Comment: yes i want if any data is present then it shows.

Comment: After the `foreach` and before the `echo` type `var_dump($tweet); die();`. That will tell you what type of variable `$tweet` is and the values it contains.

Comment: istring(1) "1"     this time this is the output

Comment: `$tweet` is not an object, it's a string with a length of 1 character and a value of "1". So therefore `$tweets` is not an array of objects. It could be an array of something else, or more likely looking at your PDO query it could be a single object. Try this `$tweets= $get_name->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);`

Comment: error is solved but this time nothing will be show

Comment: This is likely to be a problem with your SQL `select` query. Do you have a console where you can test your SQL statement before you move it to PHP?